# Having trouble correctly saving a nested form that has file_field

Tags: audio, ruby-on-rails-4

Using paperclip and ruby-mp3info to upload and read file info, I have a form that creates a playlist and its children, tracks:

```
 <%= form_for(@playlist) do |f| %>
  <% if @playlist.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@playlist.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this playlist from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @playlist.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Name: " %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label " Image: " %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
  <br>
    <%= f.text_area :description, :size => "80x3"%>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :tracks, Track.new do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.file_field :audio %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <% if !@playlist.tracks.blank? %>
  <table id="tracks" class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Track</th>
          <th>Album</th>
          <th>Artist</th>
          <th>Label</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
    <%= f.fields_for :tracks do |ff| %>
      <%= render "track_fields", :f => ff %>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
  </div>    

<% end %>
```

The problem with uploading a file is that I won't have it until I click on the Save button.  So I read the info from within my controller.  Within the update method of my Playlist controller, I try to create a new track by the following code:

```
def update

    track = @playlist.tracks.new()
    Mp3Info.open(playlist_params["tracks_attributes"]["0"]["audio"].path.to_s) do |info|

      track.audio_file_name = info.tag.title
      track.artist = info.tag.artist
      track.album  = info.tag.album
      # tracknum = info.tag.tracknum.to_s
    end


    respond_to do |format|
      if @playlist.update(playlist_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @playlist, notice: 'Playlist was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @playlist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem is that the code in my update method will create TWO instances of tracks when I only want one.  How do I create only the instance that I am creating from within my controller and ignore the new track that is being created from within the form?

Are there alternative ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting two records in `tracks` table because one you are creating from `form` (with track_attributes) and other you are creating in `update` action.

If you just need to update few properties of the track to be saved then do it on the track coming in `params[:playlist][:tracks_attributes]`.

Change the `update` action as below:

```
  def update

    Mp3Info.open(playlist_params["tracks_attributes"]["0"]["audio"].path.to_s) do |info|

      params[:playlist][:tracks_attributes]["0"][:audio_file_name] = info.tag.title
      params[:playlist][:tracks_attributes]["0"][:artist] = info.tag.artist
      params[:playlist][:tracks_attributes]["0"][:album]  = info.tag.album
      # tracknum = info.tag.tracknum.to_s
    end


    respond_to do |format|
      if @playlist.update(playlist_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @playlist, notice: 'Playlist was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @playlist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This will create only one associated `Track` record for a `Playlist` in `tracks` table.